# VS2010 - Dashes show for all spaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just bought a cool new DAS Keyboard without the letters on the keys.  Unfortunately, I was trying to hit a particular short-cut combination and I must have hit the wrong keys.  Now all of the spaces in my code files have - instead.

How do I get rid of those?

Thank you

Comment: That's pretty funny. Neat keyboards though.

Comment: You got owned by a keyboard ;)

Comment: @BenJames Yes sir, I most certainly did. :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to Edit -> Advanced and uncheck "View whitespace".

Comment: Thank you, sir.  That was driving me crazy. :)

Comment: You could also use the shortcut keys CTRL + e followed by s as found there -> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/a5265c36-b585-4d98-a5ee-59602e38fd4e/